# Cheap compatible infrared receiver

Tags: 10.10, lirc, boxee

I have a universal remote that I would like to use to control my Ubuntu box setup using boxee.

I'm pretty familiar using lirc to get it setup(which I've used with an RF remote/receiver) but I'd like to know if anyone knows of a cheap, but compatible, infrared receiver I can buy for use with a common infrared multi-system remote.

Btw, I'm running Ubuntu 10.10

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People seem to really like the [AVS Gear HA-IR01SV](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16880121001). It comes with a remote control, and it's not that cheap ($21.23 at the time of writing this) - but it's reported to work excellently.

There is also a [comprehensive compatibility list](http://www.lirc.org/html/table.html) from the people at LIRC. And it actually contains some parts that are still being sold. :)

Comment: I'm looking at something to use for my current remote, but didn't really expect much to popup :-)  Thanks for the suggestions!